# How can I add tolerance to an input search engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, logic

I have this code to search text in a big text file:

```
y = input("Apellido/s:").upper()
    for line in fread:

        if y in line:
            print(line)
```

How can I implement a way that it searches for similar text/autocorrect if nothing is found. Not as extensive as google does it, but just search for text that has maybe 1 more letter or an accent in a word. I can't imagine the algorithm to do it by myself.

*I now that i have to add an if but im asking for the logic*

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/fuzzysearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [find_near_matches](https://fuzzysearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#simple-example) from [fuzzysearch](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzysearch/)

```
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches
y = input("Apellido/s:").upper()
    for line in fread:
        if find_near_matches(y, line, max_l_dist=2):
            print(line)
```

`find_near_matches` return a list of matches if some found, if not match found it returns an empty array which is evaluated to false.

`max_l_dist` option says [the total number of substitutions, insertions and deletions](https://github.com/taleinat/fuzzysearch/blob/faa0f4d3fb30c63a7fb8eea9778372bbb3243d90/src/fuzzysearch/__init__.py#L45) (a.k.a. [the Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance))